# how to append element while jssor slider is sliding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jssor

HTML :

```
<div id="slider1_container" class="slider left">
    <div u="slides" id="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 700px; height: 710px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="sliderow">
            <div class="cell room">102</div>
            <div class="cell patient">1002</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderow">
            <div class="cell room">103</div>
            <div class="cell patient">1003</div>
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the sliding `div` tags from `javasript` function :

```
var options = {
        $AutoPlay : true,
        $AutoPlaySteps : 5,
        $AutoPlayInterval : 2500,

        $ArrowKeyNavigation : true,
        $SlideDuration : 300, 
        $SlideWidth : 700,
        $SlideHeight : 140,
        $SlideSpacing : 3,
        $DisplayPieces : 5,
        $PlayOrientation : 2,
        $DragOrientation : 2

    };

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url : 'GetList',
          type : 'post',
          dataType : 'json',
          async : false,
          success : function(result){
               for(var k = 0; result.list.length > k; k++){
                    if(k == 0){
                         $("#slides").html("<div class='sliderow'><div class='cell room'>"+result.list[k].number+"</div><div class='cell patient'>"+result.list[k].callnum+"</div></div>");
                    }else{
                         $("#slides").append("<div class='sliderow'><div class='cell room'>"+result.list[k].number+"</div><div class='cell patient'>"+result.list[k].callnum+"</div></div>");
                    }
               }
          }
    });
}, 2000);
```

`result` of `success` has a list(numbers), in every 2 seconds I want to change `div` tags

when `.append()` to `div` the style is crashes and slider is stopped..

What can I do ??

Help me.. Thank you..

Comment: try $("<div class='sliderow'><div class='cell room'>"+result.list[k].number+"</div><div class='cell patient'>"+result.list[k].callnum+"</div></div>"").appendTo('#slides');

Comment: nahh.. its same, have you more idea?

Comment: are you sure if this code is append to your #slides it may working fine

Comment: yes.. I've tried it has same problem

Comment: so may be some problem in your code not in append

Comment: maybe..I think it is impossible :P

Comment: You can't change number of slides dynamically. But you can alter content of any slide dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it by using following code.

```
var options = {
        $AutoPlay : true,
        $AutoPlaySteps : 5,
        $AutoPlayInterval : 2500,

        $ArrowKeyNavigation : true,
        $SlideDuration : 300, 
        $SlideWidth : 700,
        $SlideHeight : 140,
        $SlideSpacing : 3,
        $DisplayPieces : 5,
        $PlayOrientation : 2,
        $DragOrientation : 2

    };

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url : 'GetList',
          type : 'post',
          dataType : 'json',
          async : false,
          success : function(result){
               for(var k = 0; result.list.length > k; k++){
                    if(k == 0){
                         jssor_slider1.$ReloadSlides("<div class='sliderow'><div class='cell room'>"+result.list[k].number+"</div><div class='cell patient'>"+result.list[k].callnum+"</div></div>");
                    }else{
                         jssor_slider1.$AppendSlides("<div class='sliderow'><div class='cell room'>"+result.list[k].number+"</div><div class='cell patient'>"+result.list[k].callnum+"</div></div>");
                    }
               }
          }
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Also, you can reload slides in one go. `jssor_slider1.$ReloadSlides("html code of all slides");`

Comment: Or `jssor_slider1.$ReloadSlides(slideHtmlCodeArray);`